# Fragment content doesn't show

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments. When I try to change the second from the first, debugger join in the second fragment but the content doesn't show. I try add and replace methods but all the same. Content of the second not changed.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        RepairViewFragment fragment = new RepairViewFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detailFragment, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Thanks.

This is the code of `RepairViewFragment`

```
public class RepairViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

//  private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
//  private final static int REQUEST_BT_SETTINGS = 2;

ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;

ArrayList<MachineBT> Machines = new ArrayList<MachineBT>();

String BluetoothDevices = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    Button btn_cl = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_client_automat);
    btn_cl.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btn_own = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_own_automat);
    btn_own.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton img_back = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.img_back);
    img_back.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.repair_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: You will need to post the source for RepairViewFragment in order for us to help you.

Comment: I already public the code of this class

Answer (score 0):

hmmm i think you should put your code on the onCreateView part of the fragment, not on the activityCreated, what i know is activityCreated is used on listfrags, as in my case :D

Comment: But this hasn't matter because neither one of my views doesn't shows on display.. my problem is this that i don't see anything.. but if i add Toast in repairViewFragment ..he shows.. on the display but views not

Comment: The problem was that i have two fragments im my xml layout definied by <fragment .. /> . When i change second <fragment to other element like <LinearLayout.. all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the code you wrote inside onActivityCreated to onStart.

Comment: Alreday do this.. nothing changes